# Group elements of a list based on repetition of values

Tags: python

I am really new to Python and I am having a issue figuring out the problem below.

I have a list like:

```
my_list = ['testOne:100', 'testTwo:88', 'testThree:76', 'testOne:78', 'testTwo:88', 'testOne:73', 'testTwo:66', 'testThree:90']
```

And I want to group the elements based on the occurrence of elements that start with 'testOne'.

Expected Result:

```
new_list=[['testOne:100', 'testTwo:88', 'testThree:76'], ['testOne:78', 'testTwo:88'], ['testOne:73', 'testTwo:66', 'testThree:90']]
```

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Comment: Join with whitespace and use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split).

Comment: Does it always go "one, two, three", or are those just examples? Could there also be "one, three", or starting at e.g. "two"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just start a new list at every `testOne`.

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> for item in my_list:
        if item.startswith('testOne:'):
            new_list.append([])
        new_list[-1].append(item)

>>> new_list
[['testOne:100', 'testTwo:88', 'testThree:76'], ['testOne:78', 'testTwo:88'], ['testOne:73', 'testTwo:66', 'testThree:90']]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Not a cool one-liner, but this works also with more general labels:

```
result = [[]]
seen = set()
for entry in my_list:
    test, val = entry.split(":")
    if test in seen:
        result.append([entry])
        seen = {test}
    else:
        result[-1].append(entry)
        seen.add(test)
```

Here, we are keeping track of the test labels we've already seen in a `set` and starting a new list whenever we encounter a label we've already seen in the same list.

Alternatively, assuming the lists *always* start with `testOne`, you could just start a new list whenever the label is `testOne`:

```
result = []
for entry in my_list:
    test, val = entry.split(":")
    if test == "testOne":
        result.append([entry])
    else:
        result[-1].append(entry)
```

Answer (score 2):

It'd be nice to have an easy one liner, but I think it'd end up looking a bit too complicated if I tried that. Here's what I came up with:

```
# Create a list of the starting indices:
ind = [i for i, e in enumerate(my_list) if e.split(':')[0] == 'testOne']

# Create a list of slices using pairs of indices:
new_list = [my_list[i:j] for (i, j) in zip(ind, ind[1:] + [None])]
```

Comment: That first part could be rewritten as `ind = [i for i, e in enumerate(my_list) if e.split(':')[0] == 'testOne']`

Comment: ... and the 2nd and 3rd part to `[my_list[i:j] for (i, j) in zip(ind, ind[1:] + [None])]`. I really like this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sophisticated but it works:

```
my_list = ['testOne:100', 'testTwo:88', 'testThree:76', 'testOne:78', 'testTwo:88', 'testOne:73', 'testTwo:66', 'testThree:90']

splitting_word = 'testOne'
new_list = list()
partial_list = list()
for item in my_list:
    if item.startswith(splitting_word) and partial_list:
        new_list.append(partial_list)
        partial_list = list()
    partial_list.append(item)
new_list.append(partial_list)
```

Answer (score -2):

joining the list into a string with delimiter `|`

```
step1="|".join(my_list)
```

splitting the listing based on `'testOne'`

```
step2=step1.split("testOne")
```

appending `"testOne"` to the list elements to get the result

```
new_list=[[i for i in str('testOne'+i).split("|") if len(i)>0] for i in step2[1:]]
```

Comment: Can I get the reason for the downvote? The code is working and gives the required output

Comment: Wasn't me, but no, it doesn't give the required output. Also, it's rather hackish.

Comment: `new_list=[['testOne:100', 'testTwo:88', 'testThree:76'], ['testOne:78', 'testTwo:88'], ['testOne:73', 'testTwo:66', 'testThree:90']]` . This is what is the required output and mine gives the same

Comment: What Python version are you using? In my Python 3.5.2, it's missing that `'testThree:90'` at the end.